# How to generate sequential date field by year?

Tags: arcgis-pro, field-calculator, datetime

Looked at several similar questions but cannot find solution.

I'm working with some mosaic rasters that need a date fields added to them for a time dimension, but I don't want to do it manually. I've used the calculate field [Sequential Number function](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000018847) for regular number fields, but it doesn't seem to work for a date field. I need the dates to start 8/31/1987 and go up by year (8/31/1988, 8/31/1989, and so on). If I use pStart=8/31/1987 pInterval=365 the result is the first record starting as 12/30/1899 12:00:10 AM and going up by year from there.

[image]

Any solutions?

Comment: Are you sure that is an ArcGIS Date field and not an ArcGIS Text field?  A Date field would not show only the year unless you are using custom formatting.

Comment: @bixb0012 I am sure it is a date field, just have it set to display only the year. I think I have found a solution by just using the sequential number function to create a separate number/string field and then using the Convert Time Field Tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach not involving creating additional fields and using additional tools:

```py
# Field Name: Year
# Expression Type: Python 3
# Expression: Year = 
next(year)
# Code Block
import datetime

def increment_year():
    base_year = 1987
    base_month = 8
    base_day = 31
    counter = 0
    while True:
        yield datetime.datetime(base_year + counter, base_month, base_day)
        counter += 1

year = increment_year()
```

I am not a fan of using `global` unless it is necessary, and it isn't in this case since a generator works just fine.

Comment: this runs and delivers desired result despite an invalid expression warning "No function was found with the name 'next'."   thanks

Comment: Interesting about the warning since `next()` is [Built-in Functions -- Python 3.11.1 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)

Answer (score 1):

Solved with workaround. I used the sequential number function field calculator linked above to create a separate field and then just converted to date field using the Convert Time Field tool in geoprocessing.

[image] [image] Result:
[image]